# Coloured terminal output not working as it should using the termcolor crate

Tags: rust, terminal, zsh

I have been playing around with the [colorterm crate](https://crates.io/crates/colored). I've written a simple program in VS code here:

```
use termcolor::{Color, ColorChoice, ColorSpec, StandardStream, WriteColor, BufferWriter};
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let quote: &str = "A donkey, a donkey, my kingdom for a donkey!";

    let colors: Vec<(u8, u8, u8)> = vec![
        (50, 168, 82),
        (255, 129, 3),
        (32, 72, 145),
        (237, 226, 17), 
        (48, 176, 161), 
        (166, 28, 111),
        (230, 18, 36)
    ];

    let mut stdout = StandardStream::stdout(ColorChoice::Always);
    for color in colors {
        stdout.set_color(ColorSpec::new().set_fg(
            Some(Color::Rgb(
                color.0,
                color.1,
                color.2
            ))
        ))
            .expect("Failed to set color");
        write!(&mut stdout, "{}", quote).expect("failed to write");
        println!();
    }
}
```

Everything was going fine testing the output in the VS integrated terminal

[image: VS code integrated terminal output]

However, when I test it on my OS terminal (the Terminal.app that comes with MacOS) I get the following:

[image]

The results have the incorrect colours, are italicised in one instance or have no color (well grey I suppose) at all.

I'm thinking this is less a problem with the crate and more with my terminal config?
I use `Mac OSX` with a `zsh shell` for my normal terminal, no fancy configs but I do use `oh my zsh` normally **(I tried this on a shell without oh my zsh and got the same result)**. My first feeling was that it was something to do with the environment variable mentioned in the docs [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/termcolor#automatic-color-selection) however I've got TERM set to xterm-256color. I think the answer may lay in the configuration difference between the VS code integrated terminal (there must be something right?) and the vanilla zsh terminal. If anyone is more familiar with the differences between the two, or if you have encountered any similar problems with the crate, or I am missing something entirely here I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$TERM"` in each case? It could also be that the escape sequences understood by the VS Code terminal do not work for your other terminal. Have you tried the built-in MacOS terminal?

Comment: echo "$TERM" gives me xterm-256color in both cases. Yes the first instance (which works) is the VS code integrated terminal, the second instance (the build-in MacOS terminal, sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll edit the OP) doesn't. By escape sequences do you mean ansi out put? How could I check that?

Comment: First I would try just bash in `Terminal.app`. Then I'd try a third-party terminal app. I'm not sure how to check escape sequences but it may just be that Terminal.app doesn't recognize the same ones as VS Code.

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ, trying a 3rd party app (I used iterm2) really helped me narrow down the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just for completeness I managed to find the answer to this with some digging. The vanilla Terminal.app doesn't support [truecolor](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/146100155ecd79c7dac19a9e23e6a362); checking COLORTERM variables for each terminal (terminal.app, vs code intergrated, and iterm2) clarified this. For terminals that don't support truecolor we can convert our rbg values into a single u8 ansi256 value (for conversion I used [this](https://crates.io/crates/rgb2ansi256) library) and use the appropriate variation of the [Color](https://docs.rs/termcolor/1.2.0/termcolor/enum.Color.html) enum to output our coloured content like so:

```
...

println!("{}", val);
    let mut stdout = StandardStream::stdout(ColorChoice::Always);
    for color in colors {
        let ansi_val: u8 = rgb_to_ansi256(color.0, color.1, color.2);
        stdout.set_color(ColorSpec::new().set_fg(
            Some(Color::Ansi256(ansi_val))
        ))
            .expect("Failed to set color");
        write!(&mut stdout, "{}", quote).expect("failed to write");
        println!();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's not the exact situation I was in, but it pointed me to the fact that .truecolor() in the colored crate wasn't working on the zsh terminal on macOS. So I switched to using owo-colors with the [xterm colour defaults](https://github.com/jam1garner/owo-colors/blob/master/examples/all_xterm_colors.rs) and that was good enough.